# Auto-scroll to the last child of specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to automatically scroll the box with the last child of class ask with jquery (animation: slow), the `3 ask` should stick to the top of the div `box`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id=box style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  <span class=ask>1 ask<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></span>
  <span class=reply>2 reply<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></span>
  <span class=ask>3 ask<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></span>
  <span class=reply>4 reply<br><br><br><br><br><br><br></span>
</body>
</html>
```

LIKE THIS:

[image]

Comment: Actually there is a better way with pure JS: Take a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView (at least for the scroll part)

Comment: I don't know how to use `Element.scrollIntoView()`. :(

Comment: Read above, it shows you. Plus in jquery all you have to do is $('#box > .ask").get(0).scrollIntoView(); (Dont try this in jsfiddle it will kill it for some odd reason

Comment: @Deadweight it's actually `$(selector).last()[0].scrollIntoView()`. Since he wants to scroll to the last element.

Comment: Ah yeah i thought he just wanted to scroll to the element itself

Comment: @Deadweight almost made the same mistake answering this question. Though I hope he understands that the element won't be able to stick to the top of the div if the div can't scroll anymore.

Comment: Problem solved. :)

Comment: Hey can make it stick to the div. He just needs to use sticky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `scrollIntoView()` function. To use this with jQuery you do the following `$(selector).last()[0].scrollIntoView()` and the element will be scrolled into view.

You can couple this with the css [scrollbehaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior) property and the browser will create an auto scroll effect for you without any setup. Do be warned that this css property isn't well [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need smooth scrolling on last `span` of answer of @kitanga Nday

[you might look this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

```
$("span").last()[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```